# Appropriate power meter for CPU and GPU power consumption?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, desktop, power

I want to buy a power meter in order to measure CPU and GPU power consumption, on a remoter desktop machine (in which I have physical access). The software is ubuntu 18.04, I can measure the nvidia GPU power consumption using nvidia-smi, but I cannot measure the CPU power consumption trustworhty. I need to purchase a tool that I might place on the device and it would expose measurements to an endpoint/url for instance for the device, such as power consumption, energy consumption etc.

Would you suggest something?

Comment: Are you looking for something that can measure on a per-rail basis, or is measuring the consumption of the system as a whole fine?

Comment: The ideal would be per-rail, but even something that measures the whole system as a fine would do the job.

Comment: How about just getting a power supply that supplies per-rail information?